# Android sqlite update error no such column

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am currently making a validation and implementation with sqlite in my android apps. The purpose is to make search keyword history. So in this case, I want when the user input the same keyword but in different time, I want to push forward that keyword to become the latest keyword by updating the "time" column in the sqlite database.

Here is the code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_TIME, time);
sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME_SEARCH, values, KEY_KEYWORD + " = " + keyword, null);
```

But it returns error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lakupon, PID: 24030
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: a (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE search SET time=? WHERE keyword = a
```

NB: in this case, "a" is the keyword that I input twice, so it is trying to update the "time" in the row where the "keyword" value is "a".

I don't know why it is saying no such column, because when I print out the data list, there is a row that has a "keyword" value equals to "a", or to make it simpler, if there is no such keyword, then the code shouldn't have run at all because I have put some validation outside.

I also don't know why it says "time=?" because when I print out the "time" parameter, it has the time value that I want such as "20170724_154935".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a" is a **string**, therefore it has to be enclosed in **string delimiters** (`'`).
Like so: `... WHERE keyword = 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_TIME, time);
sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME_SEARCH,values,KEY_KEYWORD + "=?",new String[]{keyword});
```